# SQL Server restrict all users to a database (using encryption)

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I want to encrypt my database (in this example `testDB`) for all SQL Server users - even `sa`!

I used TDE and wrote these queries:

```
USE testDB
GO

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '12345678';
CREATE CERTIFICATE tdeCert WITH SUBJECT = 'TDE Certificate';

BACKUP CERTIFICATE tdeCert TO FILE = 'e:\tdecert'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (
        FILE = 'e:\hello',
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '12345678');

CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
        ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE tdeCert;

ALTER DATABASE testDB SET ENCRYPTION ON;
GO
```

But simply `testDB` and all of its tables are shown to any users without any password! Please help to do this restriction. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

TDE encrypts the data 'at rest' - i.e. it encrypts the data files themselves, and decrypts them when loading them into memory using a decryption key that is stored in the database server. This is completely transparent to applications using the data (hence the name), no application changes are required to use it and no further authentication than is already implemented on the database is required to access the data.

Where TDE comes into play is if the database files themselves are somehow stolen or transferred to a different machine without permission - they cannot be restored or otherwise decrypted without the decryption key stored in the server they were encrypted on. There's more information on TDE here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-tde

To secure the data from users by requiring a password, you need to implement SQL server logins and users, which will allow you to give certain rights to data and operations to certain users or roles. There's a walkthrough here that should get you started: https://www.concurrency.com/blog/january-2017/creating-logins-and-users-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Connect to your SQL server instance using management studio
2.Goto Security -> Logins -> (RIGHT CLICK) New Login
3.fill in user details
4.Under User Mapping, select the databases you want the user to be able to access and configure

-- Or You Can Use
--Step 1: (create a new user)
create LOGIN hello WITH PASSWORD='foo', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;


-- Step 2:(deny view to any database)
USE master;
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO hello; 


 -- step 3 (then authorized the user for that specific database , you have to use the  master by doing use master as below)
USE master;
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::yourDB TO hello;
GO
```

Comment: if you DENY THE Permission for sa then they will not able to View it

Comment: always create a new login of SQL server which you can assign to other User Instead of sa.

Comment: Thanks, Can you write an executable query for that?

Comment: USE master;
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO sa; 
Case an error message:
Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

Comment: you can try with Other User Not With Sa.you can create a New Credential for SQL Login And Disable The sa login.and for Newly Created user you can deny the Permission.

Comment: You can't use SQL Server security to prevent SA or any member of the sysadmin fixed server role from accessing your data.  Also any Windows administrator can make themselves a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.